# How to recover a notebook?

Tags: notebooks, version-10

I was closing a notebook, luckily Mathematica (10!) asked me if I really wanted to quit without saving, so I saved, but now when I open that notebook this is what I see:

[image]

Is there a way to recover the content of the notebook?

**EDIT**

Mathematica showed me this dialog:

[image]

and I clicked on "Save".

**EDIT2**
As requested:

```
(* Content-type: application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica *)

(*** Wolfram Notebook File ***)
(* http://www.wolfram.com/nb *)

(* CreatedBy='Mathematica 10.0' *)

(*CacheID: 234*)
(* Internal cache information:
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookDataPosition[       158,          7]
NotebookDataLength[     28123,        729]
NotebookOptionsPosition[     26564,        684]
NotebookOutlinePosition[     27872,        720]
CellTagsIndexPosition[     27829,        717]
WindowTitle->Wolfram Mathematica 10.0
WindowFrame->ModelessDialog*)

(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
Notebook[{
Cell[BoxData[
 PaneBox["\<\"\"\>",
  ImageSize->{Full, 9}]],
 CellMargins->0,
 CellBracketOptions->{"Color"->RGBColor[0.269993, 0.308507, 0.6]},
 CellElementSpacings->{"CellMinHeight"->1},
 CellHorizontalScrolling->True,
 PageBreakAbove->True,
 PageBreakWithin->False,
 CellLabelMargins->0,
 CellFrameMargins->0,
 CellFrameLabelMargins->0,
 ShowAutoStyles->True,
 LineSpacing->{1.25, 0},
 AutoItalicWords->{},
 ScriptMinSize->9,
 ShowStringCharacters->False,
 FontFamily:>CurrentValue["PanelFontFamily"],
 FontSize->1,
 Background->RGBColor[
  0.8980392156862745, 0.09803921568627451, 0.10980392156862745`]],

Cell[BoxData[
 PaneBox[
  DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
    FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "TitleBanner.png"]],
   ImageSizeCache->{334., {14., 18.}}],
  Alignment->Center,
  ImageMargins->{{0, 0}, {0, 20}},
  ImageSize->Full]],
 CellMargins->0,
 CellBracketOptions->{"Color"->RGBColor[0.269993, 0.308507, 0.6]},
 CellElementSpacings->{"CellMinHeight"->1},
 CellHorizontalScrolling->True,
 PageBreakAbove->True,
 PageBreakWithin->False,
 CellLabelMargins->0,
 CellFrameMargins->0,
 CellFrameLabelMargins->0,
 ShowAutoStyles->True,
 LineSpacing->{1.25, 0},
 AutoItalicWords->{},
 ScriptMinSize->9,
 ShowStringCharacters->False,
 FontFamily:>CurrentValue["PanelFontFamily"],
 FontSize->1],

Cell[BoxData[
 PaneBox[
  TagBox[GridBox[{
     {
      TagBox[
       PaneSelectorBox[{"Default"->
        TagBox[GridBox[{
           {
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "File.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{39., {17., 22.}}]},
           {
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[

              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
               "MathematicaClosingDialog", "NewNotebook"],
               ImageSizeCache->{81., {1., 9.}}],
              StripOnInput->False,

              LineColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              FrontFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              BackFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              GraphicsColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],
              FontFamily->"Helvetica",
              FontSize:>FrontEnd`CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"],

              FontColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             FontWeight->Bold]}
          },
          AutoDelete->False,

          GridBoxItemSize->{
           "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
          GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{1}}}],
         "Grid"], "Hover"->
        TagBox[GridBox[{
           {
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "File-Hover.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{39., {17., 22.}}]},
           {
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[

              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
               "MathematicaClosingDialog", "NewNotebook"],
               ImageSizeCache->{81., {1., 9.}}],
              StripOnInput->False,

              LineColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              FrontFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              BackFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              GraphicsColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],
              FontFamily->"Helvetica",
              FontSize:>FrontEnd`CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"],

              FontColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             FontWeight->Bold]}
          },
          AutoDelete->False,

          GridBoxItemSize->{
           "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
          GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{1}}}],
         "Grid"]}, FEPrivate`If[
         FrontEnd`CurrentValue["MouseOver"], "Hover", "Default"]],
       EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> DialogReturn[
           FrontEndTokenExecute["New"]], PassEventsDown -> Automatic, 
         PassEventsUp -> True}]], 
      TagBox[
       PaneSelectorBox[{"Default"->
        TagBox[GridBox[{
           {
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "Open.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{45., {15., 20.}}]},
           {
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[

              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
               "WelcomeScreen", "OpenDialogText"],
               ImageSizeCache->{42., {2., 9.}}],
              StripOnInput->False,

              LineColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              FrontFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              BackFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              GraphicsColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],
              FontFamily->"Helvetica",
              FontSize:>FrontEnd`CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"],

              FontColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             FontWeight->Bold]}
          },
          AutoDelete->False,

          GridBoxItemSize->{
           "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
          GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{1}}}],
         "Grid"], "Hover"->
        TagBox[GridBox[{
           {
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "Open-Hover.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{45., {15., 20.}}]},
           {
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[

              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
               "WelcomeScreen", "OpenDialogText"],
               ImageSizeCache->{42., {2., 9.}}],
              StripOnInput->False,

              LineColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              FrontFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              BackFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              GraphicsColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],
              FontFamily->"Helvetica",
              FontSize:>FrontEnd`CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"],

              FontColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             FontWeight->Bold]}
          },
          AutoDelete->False,

          GridBoxItemSize->{
           "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
          GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{1}}}],
         "Grid"]}, FEPrivate`If[
         FrontEnd`CurrentValue["MouseOver"], "Hover", "Default"]],
       EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> If[
           CurrentValue["LocalFileSystemAccessAllowed"], 
           FrontEndTokenExecute["Open"], 
           FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloudObject"]], PassEventsDown -> 
         Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]], 
      TagBox[
       PaneSelectorBox[{"Default"->
        TagBox[GridBox[{
           {
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "Quit.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{32., {14., 18.}}]},
           {
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[
              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResourceString["quitButtonText"],
               ImageSizeCache->{23., {1., 9.}}],
              StripOnInput->False,

              LineColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              FrontFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              BackFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],

              GraphicsColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`],
              FontFamily->"Helvetica",
              FontSize:>FrontEnd`CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"],

              FontColor->RGBColor[
               0.43137254901960786`, 0.42745098039215684`, 
                0.42745098039215684`]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             FontWeight->Bold]}
          },
          AutoDelete->False,

          GridBoxItemSize->{
           "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
          GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{1}}}],
         "Grid"], "Hover"->
        TagBox[GridBox[{
           {
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "Quit-Hover.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{32., {14., 18.}}]},
           {
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[
              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResourceString["quitButtonText"],
               ImageSizeCache->{23., {1., 9.}}],
              StripOnInput->False,

              LineColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              FrontFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              BackFaceColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],

              GraphicsColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392],
              FontFamily->"Helvetica",
              FontSize:>FrontEnd`CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"],

              FontColor->RGBColor[
               0.9294117647058824, 0.1803921568627451, 0.01568627450980392]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             FontWeight->Bold]}
          },
          AutoDelete->False,

          GridBoxItemSize->{
           "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
          GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{1}}}],
         "Grid"]}, FEPrivate`If[
         FrontEnd`CurrentValue["MouseOver"], "Hover", "Default"]],
       EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> DialogReturn[
           FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"]], PassEventsDown -> Automatic,
          PassEventsUp -> True}]]}
    },
    AutoDelete->False,
    GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{Center}}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}},
    GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{
         Scaled[0.33]}}}],
   "Grid"],
  Alignment->{Center, Center},
  ImageMargins->{{20, 20}, {30, 20}}]],
 ShowCellBracket->False,
 CellMargins->0,
 CellBracketOptions->{"Color"->RGBColor[0.269993, 0.308507, 0.6]},
 CellHorizontalScrolling->True,
 PageBreakAbove->True,
 PageBreakWithin->False,
 ShowAutoStyles->True,
 LineSpacing->{1.25, 0},
 AutoItalicWords->{},
 ScriptMinSize->9,
 ShowStringCharacters->False,
 FontFamily:>CurrentValue["PanelFontFamily"],
 FontSize:>CurrentValue["PanelFontSize"]],

Cell[BoxData[
 PaneBox[
  PaneSelectorBox[{True->
   PaneSelectorBox[{"Default"->
    TagBox[GridBox[{
       {
        TagBox[
         DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
           FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "CheckboxOff.png"]],
          ImageSizeCache->{14., {5., 9.}}],
         EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
             FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
              FrontEndObject[
               LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
              PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
             FEPrivate`Not[
              FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
               FrontEndObject[
                LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
               PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
           PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]], 
        TagBox[
         StyleBox[
          StyleBox[

           DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
            "MathematicaClosingDialog", "ToggleText"],
            ImageSizeCache->{187., {3., 9.}}], "DialogStyle",
           StripOnInput->False,
           FontColor->GrayLevel[0.8]],
          StripOnInput->False,
          LineSpacing->{1, 0},
          LineIndent->0],
         EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
             FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
              FrontEndObject[
               LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
              PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
             FEPrivate`Not[
              FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
               FrontEndObject[
                LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
               PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
           PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]]}
      },
      AutoDelete->False,
      GridBoxAlignment->{"Rows" -> {{Bottom}}},
      GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
      GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{0.5}}}],
     "Grid"], "Hover"->
    DynamicModuleBox[{$CellContext`pressedQ$$ = False}, 
     TagBox[
      PaneSelectorBox[{False->
       TagBox[GridBox[{
          {
           TagBox[
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "CheckboxOff.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{14., {5., 9.}}],
            EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                 FrontEndObject[
                  LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                 PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
                FEPrivate`Not[
                 FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                  FrontEndObject[
                   LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                  PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
              PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]], 
           TagBox[
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[

              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
               "MathematicaClosingDialog", "ToggleText"],
               ImageSizeCache->{187., {3., 9.}}], "DialogStyle",
              StripOnInput->False,
              FontColor->GrayLevel[0.8]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             LineSpacing->{1, 0},
             LineIndent->0],
            EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                 FrontEndObject[
                  LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                 PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
                FEPrivate`Not[
                 FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                  FrontEndObject[
                   LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                  PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
              PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]]}
         },
         AutoDelete->False,
         GridBoxAlignment->{"Rows" -> {{Bottom}}},
         GridBoxItemSize->{
          "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
         GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{0.5}}}],
        "Grid"], True->
       TagBox[GridBox[{
          {
           TagBox[
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "CheckboxOff.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{14., {5., 9.}}],
            EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                 FrontEndObject[
                  LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                 PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
                FEPrivate`Not[
                 FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                  FrontEndObject[
                   LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                  PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
              PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]], 
           TagBox[
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[

              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
               "MathematicaClosingDialog", "ToggleText"],
               ImageSizeCache->{187., {3., 9.}}], "DialogStyle",
              StripOnInput->False,
              FontColor->GrayLevel[0.8]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             LineSpacing->{1, 0},
             LineIndent->0],
            EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                 FrontEndObject[
                  LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                 PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
                FEPrivate`Not[
                 FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                  FrontEndObject[
                   LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                  PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
              PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]]}
         },
         AutoDelete->False,
         GridBoxAlignment->{"Rows" -> {{Bottom}}},
         GridBoxItemSize->{
          "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
         GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{0.5}}}],
        "Grid"]}, Dynamic[$CellContext`pressedQ$$]],
      EventHandlerTag[{
       "MouseUp" :> ($CellContext`pressedQ$$ = False), 
        "MouseDown" :> ($CellContext`pressedQ$$ = True), PassEventsUp -> True,
         PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]],
     DynamicModuleValues:>{}]}, FEPrivate`If[
     FrontEnd`CurrentValue["MouseOver"], "Hover", "Default"]], False->
   PaneSelectorBox[{"Default"->
    TagBox[GridBox[{
       {
        TagBox[
         DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
           FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "CheckboxOn.png"]],
          ImageSizeCache->{14., {5., 9.}}],
         EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
             FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
              FrontEndObject[
               LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
              PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
             FEPrivate`Not[
              FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
               FrontEndObject[
                LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
               PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
           PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]], 
        TagBox[
         StyleBox[
          StyleBox[

           DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
            "MathematicaClosingDialog", "ToggleText"],
            ImageSizeCache->{187., {3., 9.}}], "DialogStyle",
           StripOnInput->False,
           FontColor->GrayLevel[0.8]],
          StripOnInput->False,
          LineSpacing->{1, 0},
          LineIndent->0],
         EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
             FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
              FrontEndObject[
               LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
              PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
             FEPrivate`Not[
              FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
               FrontEndObject[
                LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
               PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
           PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]]}
      },
      AutoDelete->False,
      GridBoxAlignment->{"Rows" -> {{Bottom}}},
      GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
      GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{0.5}}}],
     "Grid"], "Hover"->
    DynamicModuleBox[{$CellContext`pressedQ$$ = False}, 
     TagBox[
      PaneSelectorBox[{False->
       TagBox[GridBox[{
          {
           TagBox[
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "CheckboxOn.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{14., {5., 9.}}],
            EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                 FrontEndObject[
                  LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                 PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
                FEPrivate`Not[
                 FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                  FrontEndObject[
                   LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                  PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
              PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]], 
           TagBox[
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[

              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
               "MathematicaClosingDialog", "ToggleText"],
               ImageSizeCache->{187., {3., 9.}}], "DialogStyle",
              StripOnInput->False,
              FontColor->GrayLevel[0.8]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             LineSpacing->{1, 0},
             LineIndent->0],
            EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                 FrontEndObject[
                  LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                 PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
                FEPrivate`Not[
                 FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                  FrontEndObject[
                   LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                  PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
              PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]]}
         },
         AutoDelete->False,
         GridBoxAlignment->{"Rows" -> {{Bottom}}},
         GridBoxItemSize->{
          "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
         GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{0.5}}}],
        "Grid"], True->
       TagBox[GridBox[{
          {
           TagBox[
            DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[
              FrontEnd`ToFileName[{"Dialogs", "Closing"}, "CheckboxOn.png"]],
             ImageSizeCache->{14., {5., 9.}}],
            EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                 FrontEndObject[
                  LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                 PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
                FEPrivate`Not[
                 FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                  FrontEndObject[
                   LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                  PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
              PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]], 
           TagBox[
            StyleBox[
             StyleBox[

              DynamicBox[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
               "MathematicaClosingDialog", "ToggleText"],
               ImageSizeCache->{187., {3., 9.}}], "DialogStyle",
              StripOnInput->False,
              FontColor->GrayLevel[0.8]],
             StripOnInput->False,
             LineSpacing->{1, 0},
             LineIndent->0],
            EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> FEPrivate`Set[
                FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                 FrontEndObject[
                  LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                 PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}], 
                FEPrivate`Not[
                 FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
                  FrontEndObject[
                   LinkObject["yw9au_shm", 3, 1]], {
                  PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]]], 
              PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]]}
         },
         AutoDelete->False,
         GridBoxAlignment->{"Rows" -> {{Bottom}}},
         GridBoxItemSize->{
          "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}},
         GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {{0.5}}}],
        "Grid"]}, Dynamic[$CellContext`pressedQ$$]],
      EventHandlerTag[{
       "MouseUp" :> ($CellContext`pressedQ$$ = False), 
        "MouseDown" :> ($CellContext`pressedQ$$ = True), PassEventsUp -> True,
         PassEventsDown -> Automatic, PassEventsUp -> True}]],
     DynamicModuleValues:>{}]}, FEPrivate`If[
     FrontEnd`CurrentValue["MouseOver"], "Hover", "Default"]]}, Dynamic[
    FrontEnd`CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {
     PrivateNotebookOptions, "FinalWindowPrompt"}]],
   ImageSize->All],
  Alignment->{Right, Center},
  ImageMargins->0,
  ImageSize->{Full, 30}]],
```

Comment: It is possible that somehow you saved a copy of `MathematicaClosingDialog.nb` which is what the image above appears to be.  If that is the case your original Notebook is probably lost.

Comment: Could you please post the content of the `.nb` you saved?  At least the first part of it if it is too long for the site software to accept?

Comment: Pardon me, I meant the raw text content of the `.nb` file itself, as opened in a text editor, not *Mathematica*, or as printed from within *Mathematica* using `FilePrint`.  I am trying to see if the saved file contains anything besides the closing dialog content.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I added the first part of the file.

Comment: It seems all of that relates to the closing dialog.  I don't think your original survived.  Sorry. :-(