# Edit Notebook options in version 10

Tags: notebooks, version-10, properties

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83229/how-to-recover-a-notebook).

I was closing a notebook without saving, Mathematica (10) showed me this dialogue:

[image]

and I clicked "Save", when I re-opened the notebook I found this dialogue:

[image]

Thanks to @ Mr.Wizard I found out that this means that Mathematica saved `MathematicaClosingDialog.nb` instead of my notebook, and now my work is gone.

Now I ask: is there a way to edit the notebook properties to avoid this behavoir?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior? I would try resetting the configuration: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464.

Comment: @YvesKlett In fact, yes: I just have to close an unsaved notebook as I described.

Comment: Strange. Did you try the reset yet?

Comment: @YvesKlett I tried the reset as you said and it looks like it works fine now. Thanks! Maybe I did something wrong during the installation process (it is unlikely, since it is automatic, but you never know...)